# django wsgi app settings

Tags: django, python-3.x, wsgi

I'm trying to run my django application using the built in `wsgi`. My directory is structured as follows:

```
/project/
    -/project/
        - settings.py
        - wsgi.py
        - urls.py
    -/app/
```

Here is the provided `wsgi.py` file, which I've modified a bit.

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

# used to be crowdlabel.settings
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

When running `python project/wsgi.py` , I get an error that the module `project` can't be found. To solve this, I change `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")`. Doing this then gives me a new error in the `get_wsgi_application()` function, `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`.

I am beyond confused so if anyone with experience could suggest what I'm doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated. As a note, the app runs fine on the test server.

Comment: You need to add the outer `project` directory to the python path. For an example, see the Django docs for [deploying with Apache and modwsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#basic-configuration), which set `WSGIPythonPath`.

Comment: What do you mean by built in ``wsgi``? Why aren't you just running ``python manage.py runserver``? There also is no ``run()`` method on ``application`` as far as I know. Don't know where you got that line from as not in generated ``wsgi.py`` file.

Comment: i need to put in in production and apparently its best to use something like nginx instead of the test server. also the application.run() was a stab in the dark, doesnt alter anything afaik

Comment: Have you looked at gunicorn, uWSGI or mod_wsgi at all? The Django documentation on deployment can be found at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/

Comment: im trying to follow the http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html tutorial, but the nginx->wsgi serving doesnt seem to be working. i figured this was a separate smaller issue

Answer (score 0):

`wsgi.py` should not be run from the command line, but from a WSGI container.  The most popular is gunicorn.  Try:

```
pip install gunicorn
gunicorn project.wsgi
```

More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/).